# How to split String Using REGEXP or Using Pattern class

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, string, pattern, matcher

This is My String

**14-Mar-16**,RTRDTG78BGXPBE3H,D-Link DIR-600M Wireless N150 Home Router,**10-Apr-16**, SECEBH7HZMKZMG3B,Kaspersky Internet Security 2016 1 PC 1 Year

I want to split this string Where ever I find the pattern which I have Highlighted.

Comment: try with this https://regex101.com/r/dS3iY4/2

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your string like this:

```
14-Mar-16,RTRDTG78BGXPBE3H,D-Link DIR-600M Wireless N150 Home Router,
10-Apr-16,SECEBH7HZMKZMG3B,Kaspersky Internet Security 2016 1 PC 1 Year
```

it appears to be a repeating pattern of 3 values separated by commas. If that is the case, personally I would just go for:

```
String[] parts = '14-Mar-16,RTR...Year'.split(',');
```

and deal with each piece based on its index in the `parts` array:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
    String part = parts[i];
    Integer type = Math.mod(i, 3);
    if (type == 0) use part as a date
    else if (type == 1) use part as a code
    else if (type == 2) use part as a name
}
```

Comment: In "typing" this, you're obviously not creating a class, but I do see the OOP logic to it. Am curious, is this somewhat akin to a factory pattern perhaps, an interface, or what would you say drove your thinking towards this approach?

Comment: @crmprogdev Yes I would also probably create a class to represent each item.  My core point is that data formats often have simple delimiters (such as commas) and using simple delimiters avoids adding code that could fail such as assuming that the day of month always has 2 numbers when it may sometimes have 1 and vice versa. Also splitting on a comma is [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) compared to using a regular expression.

Comment: Totally agree with you on the KISS and using the commas to do the split. I'd have recommended the same thing. I was simply intrigued by your "typing" the results as a means to find the dates in the list. Nice work!